# Installing BootCamp 4 drivers on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot-camp

I've installed Windows 8 on a 2nd partition on my MacBook.

Now I would like to install the BootCamp drivers from Apple, so that my hardware will work correctly.

However when I try to run Setup, I get the following error:

> Installation Error
>
> Boot Camp x64 is unsupported on this computer model

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the MSI (Microsoft Installer Package) to make it run on Windows 8.

Do the following:

1. [Download](http://www.technipages.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/orca.Msi) and install Orca for Windows 8.
2. Run Orca, click File > Open, browse to your `BootCamp\Drivers\Apple` folder and choose `BootCamp64.msi`.
3. Click LaunchCondition on the left-hand list.
4. Select all the rows then click Edit > Cut Rows.
5. Save the file and quit Orca.

Now you should be able to run `Setup.exe` (in the BootCamp root folder).

---

Source: [This humorous forum post](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/36727-YES-!-Managed-to-install-BootCamp-in-Windows-8?p=625530&viewfull=1#post625530).